# Is there a PHP equivalent to Java MessageDigest

Tags: java, php, encryption, sha256

I have a Java method that I need to implement in PHP.  It is to create an authentication string to gain access to an API.  It consists of a code given by the company as well as an API key, also given by the company, and, according to the Java example below, it also includes a GMT timestamp in minutes since epoch.

According to the documentation it says "The timestamp calculated as the number of minutes passed since epoch.  A GMT time zone must be used for calculating the timestamp.  If the system time of a requesting server is off by more than one minute from actual current time , the call will be rejected by the server with a 400 Bad Request code".

I have to provide as parameters the code as well as the SHA-256 encrypted token that I create.

Here is the Java:

```
String createToken() {
    String token = "";

    MessageDigest lclMD = null;
    try {
        lclMD = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"); }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    lclMD.update((EnvConstants.code + EnvConstants.api_key + Long.toString(getEpochMinutes())).getBytes());
    byte[] lclResult = lclMD.digest();

    sig = new String(Hex.encodeHex(lclResult));
    return token; 
}

long getEpochMinutes () {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); 
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

    cal.setTimeInMillis(now);
    return (cal.getTimeInMillis() / 60000L); 
}
```

This is what I have tried in PHP:

```
$time = (string)time()/60;   // to get the minutes since epoch, I have also tried it not casting it to a string
$code = 'thisisthecode';
$api_key = 'XXXXXXX';
$hash = hash('sha256', $code . $api_key . $time);

$curl = curl_init();
$url = "http://api.url/user/XXXX?code=thisisthecode&token=$hash"; 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
return $result;
```

When I run this code I always get a 400 Bad Request error.

To be clear, I don't know Java and now I'm guessing if I know PHP well enough because I can't get this to work.

Can anyone help me out with this?  I'm banging my head against the concrete.

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: $SHA = openssl_digest($stringSHA, 'sha512');  But i'm not sure what you are looking for, but this converts a string to sha512..

Comment: Thanks Dieter.  I am looking to replicate exactly what is returned by the Java example in PHP

Comment: Is it useful for your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44963287/how-to-reproduce-java-messagedigest-sha-256-hash-in-php

Answer (score 0):

$key = openssl_digest($stringSHA, 'sha512', true);