# How to reproduce java MessageDigest SHA-256 hash in PHP?

Tags: java, php, security, hash, sha256

I currently have been given the following java code snippet as an example of how to calculate a hash based on a supplied 'in' and 'salt' variable. In these examples the variables are hardcoded for testing:

```
package generatehash;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class GenerateHash {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String in = "abcdef12345";
        String salt = "test1";
        try {
            MessageDigest hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte[] digest = hash.digest((in + salt).getBytes());
            String out = new BASE64Encoder().encode(digest);
            System.out.println("Calculated: " + out);
        } catch(java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            System.err.println("SHA-256 is not a valid message digest algorithm. " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The output here is:

> Calculated: bfiUcT46ftaC76MCbGbpCFisFSlEY96/4CBwdtznaCE=

When attempting to run the PHP equivalent I tried the following:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$in = 'abcdef12345';
$salt = 'test1';

$out = hash('sha256', $in.$salt);

echo 'Calculated: ' . $out;
```

The output here is completely different:

> Calculated:
>   6df894713e3a7ed682efa3026c66e90858ac15294463debfe0207076dce76821

I've tried a number of variations but not hitting the mark. Is there something I'm missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java result is in base64 while the php result is in hex. You missed the step of base64 encoding the **raw** PHP result .

```
$in = 'abcdef12345';
$salt = 'test1';

$out = hash('sha256', $in.$salt,true); //3rd parameter says return raw result
echo 'Calculated: ' . base64_encode($out);
```

Outputs:

> Calculated: bfiUcT46ftaC76MCbGbpCFisFSlEY96/4CBwdtznaCE=

Example:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bb12ed98c16e2b732f29292da75aeebc36da2d48

Comment: Ahh, thank you! You're a champion. I actually had tried with the bae64_encode() and was still getting wrong results - but I see I had missed the third parameter to the hash() function.

Comment: Yes, without the 3rd parameter then PHP does some post-processing of its own on the  result.